# Django rest framework combine/nested serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 table, appointment and schedule.

**schedule** has these field: `scheduleid`, `title`, `'starttime'`, `'endtime'`, `'date'`

**appointment** has these field: `id`, `scheduleid`, `clinicid`, `'time'`, `'queueNo'`, `'date'`

schedule `starttime` is = appointment `time`. So is the `date`

When ever a user create a Appointment, it will also create a schedule as u can see on above. I know how to make a nested serializer but what i do not know is. If a schedule hasn't been created, what do i insert the scheduleid in the appointment table.

Reason is because, create appointment first, how to create so that in appointment django know how to create a scheduleid for it ?

Comment: Can you add your model classes to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a **appointment** table first and after the confirmation create **schedule** table. So remove the `scheduleid` from **appointment** instead of that add `appointmentid` to `schedule` table. This is not the only way, it's suggestion from side based on your requirements.